# istio virtualservice rewrite not working properly

Tags: amazon-eks, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar, istio-operator

I've setup EKS + istio ingress gateway following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/secure-end-to-end-traffic-on-amazon-eks-using-tls-certificate-in-acm-alb-and-istio/ and it works fine. I want to add uri prefix in virtualservice such that http://domain.tld/vote needs to be displaying vote app created in another namespace in the cluster.

I've used the following istio virtualservice. https://domain.tld works fine however https://domain.tld/vote shows broken layout. screenshot: https://i.is.cc/1ah4YkVU.png

This is the voting app I used for vote service - https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app which use multiple containers. Can someone shed some light on this please?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: yelb-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https-443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        credentialName: "tls-secret"
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vote
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - yelb-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /vote
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: vote.vote2.svc.cluster.local
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: yelb-ui
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - yelb-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: yelb-ui
            port:
              number: 80
      match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
```

without a rewrite rule, http://domain.tld/vote was showing 404 errors. with the above rewrite rule,the url is loading but the layout is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one single virtual service like below instead of two.  As the port number defined in service 5000 you can mention the same in virutal service.  Also in service definition you can use type as "ClusterIP" instead of NodePort.  And add "protocol: TCP" in your service definition.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vote
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - yelb-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /vote    
    route:
    - destination:
        host: vote.vote2.svc.cluster.local 
        port:
          number: 5000
    - uri:
        prefix: /    
    route:
    - destination:
        host: yelb-ui.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: <yelb-service-port-number>
```

Comment: added 5000 in virtualservice but no changes. http://domain & http://domain/vote needs to be pointing to svc in multiple ns.

https://domain works but https://domain/vote show broken layout

svc is of ClusterIP

NAME     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
db       ClusterIP   10.100.221.195   <none>        5432/TCP   19h
redis    ClusterIP   10.100.97.213    <none>        6379/TCP   19h
result   ClusterIP   10.100.84.226    <none>        5001/TCP   19h
vote     ClusterIP   10.100.231.245   <none>        5000/TCP   19h

Comment: http://domain/vote loads fine with it but both http://domain/ & http://domain/vote shows the same service (vote.vote2.svc.cluster.local ) now. How can they be pointing to seperate services?

Comment: Nataraj, its ALMOST fixed thanks. https://domain/vote loads fine (broken layout issue fixed) with virtualservice definition you provided. But https://domain shows the same application as of https://domain/vote . How can https://domain pointing to another svc in the default namespace?

Comment: More details are required on the query You mean www.abc.com should become www.def.com?

Comment: Nataraj, No. Here's my requirement:

http://example.com needs to be pointing to yelb-ui service in the default namespace   &
http://example.com/vote needs to be pointing to vote service in the "vote2" namespace

Both the services are of type ClusterIP.

Comment: example.com/demo works when I use an nginx service in a separate namespace.

 but example.com/vote shows a broken layout. example.com/vote is loading fine when  I tried the virtualservice given in your initial reply, but https://example.com needs to be pointing to another svc in default namespace

Comment: For easy maintenance if service / application pod are different name spaces then you can have two gateway and two virtual service.   Or in destination you can specify yelb-ui.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local

Comment: Natraj  I tried but not working. Could you please provide the corresponding virtualservice and gateway entry for both the services?

Comment: Updated the virtual service in the answer